# Int32 does not implement IRequest (Parameter 'request')

Tags: c#, mediatr

I am trying to implement `Mediatr` and `CQRS` pattern. I get it work for the `Create` command and `Get` query. But when I attempt to run the `Delete` command with a parameter, I got this error

> Int32 does not implement IRequest (Parameter 'request')

This is my code.

```
public class DeleteMarketingEventCommand : IRequest<int>
{
    public int Id{ get; }

    public DeleteMarketingEventCommand(int id)
    {
        Id = id;
    }
}

public class DeleteMarketingEventHandler : IRequestHandler<DeleteMarketingEventCommand, int>
{
    private readonly IMarketingEventService _marketingEventService;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public DeleteMarketingEventHandler(IMapper mapper, IMarketingEventService marketingEventService)
    {
        _mapper = mapper;
        _marketingEventService = marketingEventService;
    }

    public async Task<int> Handle(DeleteMarketingEventCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await _marketingEventService.DeleteMarketingEvent(request.Id);
        return result;            
    }
}

    [HttpDelete]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteMarketingEventById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            var result = _mediator.Send(id);
            return Ok(result);         
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Problem(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What exactly did you expect this to do, `_mediator.Send(id);` ? You're just shouting a number to mediatr, how would it know that you meant by that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the DeleteMarketingEventCommand:

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteMarketingEventById(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var result = _mediator.Send(new DeleteMarketingEventCommand(id));
        return Ok(result);         
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

or

```
     public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteMarketingEventById(DeleteMarketingEventCommand command)
{
    try
    {
        var result = _mediator.Send(command);
        return Ok(result);         
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Problem(ex.Message);
    }
}
```